# Why are my mapped drives so slow?

Tags: drivers, debian, network-shares, mybook

I have a network mapped drive that sometimes is very slow, as it is not always slow would be difficult to figure out the problem, I am wondering what would be the reason.

Some other people are using it and it's slow on every single computer.

I am using a My Book Live Duo, once I restart it, it's much faster.

I checked the system it shows following messages,

- > The network link is down or has become intermittent. Please check your network connection.
- > Drive failed in location B

I use the following:

- Linux Debian
- MyBook Live Duo
- All operating are systems Windows 7

The network mode is static on MyBook Live Duo

Comment: Please include what operating systems, network connections and hardware are being used.

Answer (score 0):

It is too complicated to describe everything but this is what the Windows Performance Monitor stuff is for.

On a Windows server, set up a performance monitor window with all the things that could possibly be relevant such as network traffic, errors, disk traffic, CPU usage, etc. Also check your event logs for interesting things happening when it is slow such as backups, shadow volume copies, RAID controller errors, SMART errors, or who knows what.

On a Linux server, I recommend logging into the command line using SSH, then using `vmstat 1` or `iostat -x -k /dev/sd[a-z] 1` to view disk usage. `atop` is another good tool. Use `less /var/log/syslog` or `less /var/log/messages` to see the system log. `dmesg` is a fast way to see the kernel log for RAID or disk errors. `netstat -s` will show network traffic stats including errors. `watch -d 'netstat -s'` is quite handy.

Comment: Actually some other people are using it and its slow on every single computer

Comment: Edited to add: Do this on the server.

Comment: it is a Debian DNS server and MY book live duo I am not sure how to do that :(

Comment: I used vmstat1 but it shows the commend is not found and used less /var/log/messages but it should permission is denied although I logged in using admin credentials